# I am trying to use opencv_cam pkg in ros2 humble with a csi stereo camera imx219-83 in a jetson nano and I get green screen

Tags: ros2, opencv, camera, stereo-vision, stereo-camera

I am trying to use opencv_cam in ros2 humble for a csi stereo cam in a jetson nano. When I run the node : `ros2 run opencv_cam opencv_cam_main` ,it publishes the image_raw topic but I only see a green image.

I have tried to use a pkg called `csi-camera-ros-wrapper` and the camera works, but it has lag in only one image (I don't know why).

This make me think that the cameras are connected correctly and there is some trouble with anything else.

My main idea is to have a node the image_raw topics of both cameras being published without lag.

Hope someone got a solution for this.